# Using subsrt() with method the_title()

Tags: php, substr

I'm trying to substring the title which it is called via the method  `the_title()` .

Here are 2 things I did to do it but they both failed.

first try: `<?php echo substr(the_title(),1,15) ?>`

second try: `<?php $new_title = the_title() ; echo substr($new_title, 1,15) ?>`

They both didn't work. when I used the `second try` I still get the full title.

Note: I'm trying to implement this on a `Wordpress` script, also it's for my php practice.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_title) does not return the title as string but outputs it by default.

Use `the_title('','', 1)` which makes it return the title or the alternative function [`get_the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_title) instead.

Comment: Oh you are right, I forgot about that, let me try the `get` one.

Comment: using `get_the_title` with `substr` worked fine, it didn't work for `the_title('','',1) tho.